# How to fix:ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace 'DATA' error while copying data from one column into another column in same table

Tags: oracle, plsql, tablespace

I am trying to copy values of one column into another column of the same table with different name with below code, however running into an error mentioned in subject line. How I can fix it?

```
  INSERT INTO T1 (C1)
     SELECT C2
      FROM T1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The user you are connected with seems to have a quota you exceeded!

First check you quotas:

```sql
SQL> select * from user_ts_quotas;

TABLESPACE_NAME      BYTES  MAX_BYTES     BLOCKS MAX_BLOCKS DRO
--------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---
USERS                    0    1048576          0        128 NO

SQL>
```

and then either remove:

```sql
alter user your_user_name quota unlimited on your_tablespace_name;
```

or change your quota:

```sql
alter user your_user_name quota 10M on your_tablespace_name;
```